# Optimise MySQL ORDER BY RAND() on a filtered GROUP BY query to avoid temp/indexless join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

MySQL "join without index" counter is incrementing as shown in various analysis tools like mysql-tuner.pl etc, having tracked down to a query which selects a random product using RAND(), I would like to optimise to help avoid this increment.

The query looks like this:

```
select p.*, count(u.prodid) as count from prods p 
left outer join usage u on p.prodid=u.prodid 
where p.ownerid>0 and p.active=1
group by p.prodid
order by rand() limit 1;
```

I've tried using this style also...

```
select p.*, count(u.prodid) as count from prods p
left outer join usage u on p.prodid=u.prodid
where prodid in 
(select prodid from prods 
where ownerid>0 and active=1 
group by prodid order by rand() limit 1);
```

but MySQL doesn't support a LIMIT in an 'in' subquery...

The explain/describe looks like this...

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range | ownerid       | ownerid | 4       | NULL |   11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | index | NULL          | userid  | 8       | NULL |   52 | Using index                                  | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Whilst some of you may think "so what if it performs an index-less join", perhaps it's more an annoyance than something that could be a problem, but I appreciate there may be a better way to achieve what is needed anyway particularly as the table row counts grow...

So any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's faster to run several queries than sorting the table by `rand()`. Firstly get the random number of the row:

```
select floor( count(*) * rand() ) random_number
from prods
where ownerid > 0 and active = 1
```

And then get the particular row:

```
select p.*, count(u.prodid) as count 
from prods p
left outer join usage u on p.prodid = u.prodid
where prodid = (
    select prodid from prods 
    where ownerid > 0 and active = 1 
    limit {$random_number}, 1
)
```

*By the way your subquery returns only one field, so you can use `=` instead of `in` operator.*

Comment: `limit count -1,1` is not going to work. You meant `limit {$count-1},1`

Comment: @Johan it's just an example explaining the idea. I don't know which programming language OP uses :)

Comment: Thanks... in the end I turned it into three queries... query to get the count, determine random number between 0 and count-1, a query to get the prodid for the random product, finally the query to do the join on usage with group by.... had to use the 2nd query because for some very weird reason, doing the subquery for the id instead of the separate 2nd query resulted in 0 returned data, very odd.

Comment: @KeithHall I think you can do this in two queries. I have edited my answer a little.